# How to I add rows/entries to existing data

Tags: r, kaggle

The Kaggle competition asks for exactly 418 entries and I only have about 250 on mine. There are only 2 columns which are: PassengerId which will be from 250 to 418 and Survived which consists of 0 and 1's.

So yeah, any suggestions on how I can add those extra 200 entries?

Comment: perhaps `?rbind()` can provide the solution.

Comment: If your original data frame is called `df` then you could try `df2 <- rbind(df, data.frame(PassengerId = 250:418,  Survived = sample(c(0, 1), 169, replace = TRUE)))`

Comment: It sounds like there is a data set you are missing. You should probably have a training data set and a prediction data set for which you don't know the true response values, but you do have the predictor values.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you. df2 is now data whilst df is under values in the global environment. How to I actually join them together?

Comment: @GregorThomas I was asked specifically to split train and test from the train data only. I would do the whole thing like you suggested But I'm so exhausted I just want to move on from this data altogether

Comment: @mimilo df2 _is_ the joined together data frame. It has the values from `df` at the top, and the new values at the bottom.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.